# NSView - get superview hierarchy

Tags: cocoa, superview

Is there a simple way to walk back up the NSView hierarchy (superview of superview of superview of nsview) to the main window or a point in between?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSView *aView = myView;
while ((aView = [aView superview])) {
    NSLog(@"%@", aView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A view won't necessarily have anything to do with “the main window”, for any definition of that term, but you can get the window that a view is in by simply [asking it](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/window).

Comment: Thanks, I actually meant contentView of window but in reality I wasn't even going back that far up the chain...